# java.awt classes in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, awt

I am working on a game application, which uses `java.awt` classes, just like `java.awt.point`. It is no problem if I compile to desktop, but it causes error messages under android.

> Not found...

How can I import or use these classes? These are very important for the proper functionality of this application. I have found a project(An attempt to facilitate AWT rendering on the Android platform), but it is now closed and all the files have been deleted, I think: https://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/

Comment: AWT isn't supported in Android as you can see in http://www.zdnet.com/article/java-vs-android-apis/ or a better source http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html . As you saw in the site you posted the author abandoned the project due to too many issues.

Comment: Yes, I see, but where can I find a fix for this issue?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315222/libgdx-conditionally-use-java-or-android-classes.  The general answer to your question is "no, that is not supported", if you update your question with the specific AWT dependencies you have you may get a more useful answer.

Comment: I use only java.awt.rectangle and java.awt.point.