# Libgdx app crashes on Android: Could not find class 'java.awt.Rectangle',

Tags: android, linux, crash, libgdx

I have a problem with running project on android device.  When I run it as desktop app everything is fine. I tried to run it on other devices but results were same.

Here is the .java code from core project:

```
public class UGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture leftPaddleImage;
    private Rectangle leftPaddle;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        leftPaddleImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("LeftPaddle_.png"));
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

        leftPaddle= new Rectangle();
        leftPaddle.x=0;
        leftPaddle.y=(480/2) - 43;
        leftPaddle.height=80;
        leftPaddle.width=20;
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(leftPaddleImage, leftPaddle.x, leftPaddle.y );
        batch.end();

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            leftPaddle.y+=200*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        }

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)) {
            leftPaddle.y-=200*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        }
    }
}
```

here is LogCat output:

```
03-04 22:06:29.728: D/ActivityThread(9937): handleBindApplication:com.studiU.qPyong.android
03-04 22:06:29.738: D/ActivityThread(9937): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
03-04 22:06:29.738: D/ActivityThread(9937): setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
03-04 22:06:29.838: D/dalvikvm(9937): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.studiU.qPyong.android-2/libgdx.so 0x41b459b8
03-04 22:06:29.858: D/dalvikvm(9937): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.studiU.qPyong.android-2/libgdx.so 0x41b459b8
03-04 22:06:29.858: D/dalvikvm(9937): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.studiU.qPyong.android-2/libgdx.so 0x41b459b8, skipping init
03-04 22:06:29.868: E/dalvikvm(9937): Could not find class 'java.awt.Rectangle', referenced from method com.studiU.qPyong.UGame.create
03-04 22:06:29.868: W/dalvikvm(9937): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1007 (Ljava/awt/Rectangle;) in Lcom/studiU/qPyong/UGame;
03-04 22:06:29.868: D/dalvikvm(9937): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0027
03-04 22:06:29.878: W/dalvikvm(9937): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 5355
03-04 22:06:29.878: D/dalvikvm(9937): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x002a
03-04 22:06:29.878: D/dalvikvm(9937): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2c85 at 0x29 in Lcom/studiU/qPyong/UGame;.create
03-04 22:06:29.888: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:290>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.005_msm7627a_JB_CL2577695_release_AU (CL2577695)
03-04 22:06:29.888: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Build Date: 07/11/12 Wed
03-04 22:06:29.888: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Local Branch: mybranch65565
03-04 22:06:29.888: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Remote Branch: quic/master
03-04 22:06:29.888: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Local Patches: NONE
03-04 22:06:29.888: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.005 + db7e81a + 4568683 + dfff884 +  NOTHING
03-04 22:06:30.038: I/AndroidInput(9937): sensor listener setup
03-04 22:06:30.098: I/AndroidInput(9937): sensor listener tear down
03-04 22:06:30.139: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:290>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.005_msm7627a_JB_CL2577695_release_AU (CL2577695)
03-04 22:06:30.139: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Build Date: 07/11/12 Wed
03-04 22:06:30.139: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Local Branch: mybranch65565
03-04 22:06:30.139: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Remote Branch: quic/master
03-04 22:06:30.139: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Local Patches: NONE
03-04 22:06:30.139: I/Adreno200-EGL(9937): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.005 + db7e81a + 4568683 + dfff884 +  NOTHING
03-04 22:06:30.209: D/OpenGLRenderer(9937): Enabling debug mode 0
03-04 22:06:30.439: I/Timeline(9937): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41b3c998 time:11125210
03-04 22:06:31.640: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(9937): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-04 22:06:31.640: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(9937): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: I don't see the actual crash in the log provided. Could you be more specific about it (i.e. specify only lines related to crash or provide another log where we can see the information about your app crash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has its own graphics library, you won't be able to use java.awt libraries in android. (The Rectangle class

```
03-04 22:06:29.868: W/dalvikvm(9937): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1007 (Ljava/awt/Rectangle;) in Lcom/studiU/qPyong/UGame;
```

You will need to find some alterantive libraries to do what you want, have a look at the one presented in [LibGDX - Conditionally use java or android classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315222/libgdx-conditionally-use-java-or-android-classes)

The libgdx libraries might be able to do what your looking for.
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/package-summary.html

Try using the Polygon class

Comment: I just found out  I was using wrong import (" java.awt.Rectangle" instead of "com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle" ). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle instead of java.awt.Rectangle